# Using NCrunch with Resharper

Tags: resharper, ncrunch

In a day to day usage, how well does [NCrunch](http://www.ncrunch.net) play with ReSharper? Can they be run side by side without any (usablilty) glitches? Is performance still OK? Anything to watch out for? Does the ReSharper testrunner still work?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I use both with no issues. I only use the Resharper test runner for debugging - it sometimes it gives better error feedback. You really need have a multicore machine for NCrunch. It always tries to run on the core that VS isn't using so it won't affect VS performance. Resharper is leaner but runs on the same core as VS so it will harm performance more.

Answer (score 15):

I use ReSharper 6 and NCrunch. If you have a multi-core machine (and you're a TDD person) than NCrunch is a must have. It gives a constant feedback of how your code looks like from the tests point of view. It instantly shows you test coverage - great sidekick. ReSharper on the other hand is a refactoring tool for me.

I run tests with ReSharper like I used to, NCrunch works in a background all the time.

From what I've spotted from time to time NCrunch and ReSharper report failing tests when the other one reports everything fine. Each time in a situation like this it turns out that there is something wrong in the code. When NCrunch is set to run in parallel some new flaws may be found :)

IMHO they both complement each other.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using NCruch for a while now in combination with Resharper

NCrunch is great, but be mindfull that NCrunch is still in beta now, and that it still has some rough edges from time to time

My NCrunch installation sometimes doesn't "see" the latest sources and starts complaining that in can't compile. I've also had some problems with casting from dynamic

But for the rest, a great tool. TDD rocks!

BTW: http://continuoustests.com/ might be worth a look too :-)

Answer (score 1):

When Resharper solution analysis and nCrunch boths runs it freezes my text editor.

Too much for my six cores.

Solution is 14 projects and about 120k lines of code.